# How to use DateAdd function in Linq?

Tags: asp.net, linq, dateadd

I have an events that users can post and related comments can be added for each events, although i have my db engine resides in the server in Us but i am living in east Europe(Cy) and we have like 7-8 hours time differences. I am using Linq anonymous type for both Events and Comments so i like to know how to use DateAdd function to correct the time differences in the Datetime of comments especially.

Here is the example of my linq expression;

```
var myEvents = from a in myEntities.AddEvents
               where a.Authorized == true
               orderby a.Id descending
               select new
               {
                   a.Id,
                   a.VenueName,
                   a.EventType,
                   a.Date,
                   a.StartTime,
                   a.EndTime,
                   a.Address,
                   a.Phone,
                   a.Reviews (This is for "Comments" and where i stuck!)
               };
```

Any ideas appreciated! Thanks

Comment: why aren't you storing your datetimes as utc?

Comment: It may help to specify the dialect of LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime.AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) for example

```
var myEvents = from a in myEntities.AddEvents
               ...
               select new
               {
                   ...
                   Date = a.Date.AddHours(7),
                   ...
               };
```

Similar methods exist for adding [days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx), [months](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx), [years](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx), [minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx), [seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds.aspx), or [milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmilliseconds.aspx).

For entity framework, however, you'll need to use [`EntityFunctions.AddHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383050.aspx) or it's allies.

Comment: Hi, when i try the above code i get this error;
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddHours(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @MutluWest I believe you need to use [`EntityFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383061.aspx). See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry my belated reply! i am checking it right now! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime while inserting the Events and Comments, e.g

```
DateTime CommentDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Arabic Standard Time"));
```

Please check the following link how to use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime

http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-_net-convert-datetime-from-one-timezone-to-another-7e44y.aspx

Comment: Ok but i am fairly new and i don't know how to implement the above code i mean where to put and how to use it like. Could you please explain more specifically? Thanks!

Comment: use this code when you are inserting the comment. The converted date specific to your Time zone will be present in your database record. No need for any conversion when you retrieve the comment.

Comment: Hi, i don't know how am i going to integrate this into a linq anonymous type expression, the thing is i am quite new with linq and i am really stuck with the above code(myCode). Reviews represents the Review Tbl and ReviewDate resides in this tbl and i need to integrate the TimeZonInfo funtionality into this column, and how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now resolved, thank you very much! I basically used a foreach loop while i am modifying the subjected column as using addHours function. It's all working as desired now.. None of the below solutions applies though Great Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for the DateAdd in Linq:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(YourInteger)
DateTime.Now.AddHours(YourInteger)
```

...and so on. The best way to use this is by making a new variable, or you will run into errors.

```
DateTime yourDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
```

After this you can use the variable you created to validate the data in Linq.

If you do:

```
new entityStuff{
    field = o.date >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(X) //months, days... you have other methods besides this one!
}
```

You will run into an error.

You should do it this way, worked with me at least!

```
new entityStuff{
    field = o.date >= yourDate
}
```

Hope it helps you, it helped me =)